# Complex (custom method call) Dynamic Filtering at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In SQL one could pass a  complex where clause as a string like some date calculation, this even at runtime. For example, letting a (poweruser) user define the where clause which can contains custom predefined functions like date functions.

How to do the same thing in pure C# when filtering a datatable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LINQ you can use this dynamic implementation that creates expression trees out of LINQ-like strings.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Hi it seems that what I need
"In a future blog post I'll delve further into building dynamic LINQ queries"

but it seems there's no part II yet :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Linq to query your DataTable.

If you don't want or can't use Linq then you can use a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) with a [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx). You can type things like:

```
dataView.RowFilter="LastName = 'Smith'";
```

or:

```
dataView.RowFilter="Isnull(Col1,'Null Column') = 'Null Column'"
```

The [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) documentation includes examples of how to connect it to a DataTable.

The expression syntax is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx). There are a lot of things defined, but it seems that there is not much for DateTimes unfortunately.

Comment: Hi the problem is the functions included in expression syntax is limited to what Microsoft allowed. I want to use CUSTOM functions.

But thanks for answer.